# Serve images to canvas from CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

So we are using images from CloudFront (which has S3 as origin) to render images on HTML5 canvas.

As expected we needed to change the 'Behaviors' of the CloudFront distribution to allow 'OPTIONS' as one of the HTTP methods and also Whitelist our S3 origin.

Having done that, the canvas is able to use images from CloudFront without any 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' errors. However the errors disappear only for the images added to S3 after making the configuration changes. The images previously added still encounter the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error.

Any idea how to solve this without having to upload all images again ?

Comment: Have you tried invalidating your CloudFront cache?

Comment: Hadn't done it earlier, did now. Shows random behaviour.

Comment: Define "random behavior". Did you wait a few minutes after clearing the cache?

Comment: Yes. Waited a good few minutes. The error occurs sometimes and sometimes the image is rendered successfully

Comment: Hmm, perhaps try clearing your browser's cache as well?

Comment: Did all that, still no luck !